# Javascript - How print even numbers from a odd number input? Also, how to display console.log on HTML( optional )?

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

After research on strackoverflow I have written/coppied this function with help from others questions.

```
function evenOrOdd() {
  var value = [];
  value = document.getElementById('evenField').value;
  value = parseInt(value);
  if(evenField != ""){
    if(value%2==1){
        console.log(`${value} is an odd number next 10 digit will be`);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
        value = value + 2;
        document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML = console.log(`Number ${i} is ${value}`);
      }
    }else{
        console.log(`${value} is an even number next 10 digit will be`);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i = i + 1){
        value = value + 2;
        document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML = console.log(`Number ${i} is ${value}`);
      }
    }
  }else{
    document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML = "";
    
  }

}

evenOrOdd(10)
```

An exemple of output for it when the user types 11 ( an odd number ) is:

```
11 is an odd number  next 10 digit will be
array-interger.js:10 Number 1 is 13
array-interger.js:10 Number 2 is 15
array-interger.js:10 Number 3 is 17
array-interger.js:10 Number 4 is 19
array-interger.js:10 Number 5 is 21
array-interger.js:10 Number 6 is 23
array-interger.js:10 Number 7 is 25
array-interger.js:10 Number 8 is 27
array-interger.js:10 Number 9 is 29
array-interger.js:10 Number 10 is 31
```

And for a even number is:

```
12 is an even number next 10 digit will be
array-interger.js:16 Number 1 is 14
array-interger.js:16 Number 2 is 16
array-interger.js:16 Number 3 is 18
array-interger.js:16 Number 4 is 20
array-interger.js:16 Number 5 is 22
array-interger.js:16 Number 6 is 24
array-interger.js:16 Number 7 is 26
array-interger.js:16 Number 8 is 28
array-interger.js:16 Number 9 is 30
array-interger.js:16 Number 10 is 32
```

My question is how can I change it to print only even number after the user types an odd number?.
Optional, how can I display the console.log on inside a HTML tag?

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <h1>Evens or Odds Numbers</h1>
            <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" name="form" method="POST">
                <div class="mb-3">
                 <label for="evenField" class="form-label">Enter a number</label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="evenField" name="evenField" min="1" max="99">
                 <small id="console-log" class="text-success"></small>
                </div>
                
                <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-12"
                onclick="evenOrOdd()">
                    Submit</button>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried to change the line

`value = value + 2;`
to

`value = value + 1;`
But it is printing both odd and even numbers

Comment: You need to round the odd number to the next even number.

Comment: Math.round(value + 1 )? It worked but is jumping the very next number.

Comment: In the odd loop you can try `value + i` instead of `value + 2`

Comment: It show works to show the very next number, but somehow after the third number shows a even again. Also if I change i = i + i it works, but count 4 times and jumps some numbers

Comment: @ifempty I added an answer just for the demo. I hope it will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print the next 10 odd number if value is even , and the next even numbers if the value is odd.

```js
const evenOrOdd = () => {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById('evenField').value);
  if (value) {
    document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML = "<br />" + `${value} is an ${ value % 2 == 1?'odd':'even'} number next 10 digit will be`

    const arr = [...Array(10).keys()];

    const result = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
      const nextNum = index > 0 ? parseInt(acc[index]) + 2 : parseInt(acc) + 2;

      document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML += "<br />" + `Number ${index+1} is ${acc[index]}`
      return [...acc, nextNum];
    }, [value + 1])
  } else {
    document.getElementById('console-log').innerHTML = ''
  }



}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <h1>Evens or Odds Numbers</h1>
      <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();evenOrOdd()" name="form" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="evenField" class="form-label">Enter a number</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="evenField" name="evenField" min="1" max="99">
          <small id="console-log" class="text-success"></small>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" onclick="evenOrOdd()">
                    Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works like a charm! Very well done!

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
function evenOrOdd(val) {
  let value = parseInt(val);
  if(value%2==1){
    console.log(`${value} is an odd number next 10 digit will be`);
    printNumbers(value);
  }else{
    console.log(`${value} is an even number next 10 digit will be`);
        printNumbers(value);
  }
}

function printNumbers(value) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    let n = value + i;
    console.log(`Number ${i} is ${n}`);
    value = value + 1
  }
}

evenOrOdd(11);
```

Comment: I'm getting NaN for this snippet

Comment: What `number` you are passing in `evenOrOdd` method ? It is working fine for both types. For ex. : `11` as well as `'11'`